# Change Snow Leopard System Font Color

Tags: snow-leopard, color

This seems like it should be simple, but I've googled and gooled and still can't find an answer.

How can I change the System font color on Mac OS X 10.6.7?

Comment: Why in the name of all that is good would you want to do this?

Comment: @Mark Why not? Some people may want to use a different color.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini: Why? Is there some *reason* they'd want a different color? It seems strange as to why anyone would want to do this, as just about any other color would be less readable than the default.

Comment: It's a reasonable question- in this case, my menu bar has a dark theme, so I want to change the color of the text in it.

Comment: @Mark It's really not your prerogative to make such a judgment. While I agree that there is seemingly no reason to change the system font color, the person didn't ask for your opinion on whether or not he should.

Comment: @Mark There's a saying that reads: "For tastes, that's why color was invented" (a rough translation from spanish). It's a perfectly reasonable idea wanting to experiment and change the theme. OS X's default theme is not the "final" word in how things should be and I can see places where I'd change a lot of things, especially after more than seven years using it. Sadly, as already addressed, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple removed official support for "skinning" Mac OS X aeons ago. The only changes that you can make easily involve installing new icon sets.

There is no way to do this short of hacking binary files.